# Focus Input Mid-Way Through Text

Tags: javascript, html

I know it's pretty easy to focus an input using JavaScript/ jQuery, but is it possible to focus the input on a certain character?

So take this input:

[image: inputExample]

Would it be possible to focus the element and have the cursor be placed after the first sentence, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure :

```
$('#inputID').focus().get(0).setSelectionRange(12, 12);
```

works in most browsers, but older IE uses `createTextRange` and `move()`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/usvdN/)

**EDIT:**

five minute plugin:

```
$.fn.setCaret = function(pos) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var elem = this,
            range;

        if (elem.createTextRange) {
            range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', pos);
        } else {
            if (elem.selectionStart !== undefined) {
                elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

to be called like:

```
$('#inputID').focus().setCaret(12);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/usvdN/3/)

Comment: Sweet, thanks!  Didn't know about that setSelectionRange()!

Also: probably going to use vanilla JS rather than set up a plugin.  The way it works on my end makes it easier.  Points for trying though!

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica - just be aware that `setSelectionRange` only works in IE9, older versions will need the `range.move()` code above, if you intend to support IE8 and below.

Comment: Right on.  The site I'm working on doesn't even technically support IE, so I'm not ultra worried about non-compliant browsers. Good thing to keep in mind though, thanks for the tip.